# Serve a file from public in a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

In my project, we have a single-page application, and our build process compiles the application into a single, static file at `public/index.html`.

The single-page application is responsible for handling all the routing in the app, so no matter whether you visit `site.com` or `site.com/foo/bar/action` or `site.com/☃`, I want the Rails application to serve `public/index.html`

I have this route:

```
match '*path', to: 'foo#index', via: :all
```

And in FooController:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render 'index.html', layout: false
  end
end
```

This does not work as I would hope; I get the error `Missing template foo/index.html, application/index.html`

Is it possible to serve an assets from `public` as part of a Rails controller action?

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 5 I got this to work by doing

```
render file: "public/examplename.html", layout: false
```

Answer (score 0):

This was way easier than I thought it would be.

I changed:

```
render 'index.html', layout: false
```

to

```
render 'public/index.html', layout: false
```

and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have changed.  I'm trying to temporarily render a static file for the admin portion of my app, which will be a VueJS SPA that talks to rails via an API.  I had to do the following:

routes.rb

```
  match '*path', :to => 'console#index', :constraints => { :subdomain=>'console'}, :via=>:all
```

console_controller.rb

```
class ConsoleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :file=>'/public/console/index.html', :layout=>false
  end
end
```

So using :file instead of no parameter on the path - because otherwise Rails 5 was trying to treat it like a normal view template.

With that path matching and a subdomain, this seems to work well, as all routes will pass through to the VueJS router.